# Grouping data by date in ireport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, record

I made ​​a report as of the date of purchase transactions.
I want to display the format as below:

[image]

In pictue above the date is only displayed once at the top.

Now, the date shown in each record that appears.
[image]

I already have the solution using subreport. In my report i select distinct for the date. And subreport using parameter from primary report.
But the problem now is, the data in each date is duplicate in every row. 
[image]

How to handle that?

Comment: are you sending data as object in jasper file?

Comment: I use sql query in my report, the data just range of the date from my Application.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. Can you post your jrxml code to understand it in better way?

Comment: This my jrxml file -> [link](https://gist.github.com/fanjava/7133085)

Comment: I am unable to open this file. can you provide me authentication.

Comment: Oke it works for now. Thanks for your help.
The solution is, I use distinct in Date in my primary report. And i add subreport that use parameter for primary report. 

Thanks for your respond ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Subreport to do this. Example i will have two sql, the first sql i will call DISTINCT all date and then the second sql (use for subreport) i will get all data have date like date in the first sql (using parameter). (Sorry my English is not good, i can'tardescrip all for you :).)

Comment: Hello, please see my update in question thank you ^^

Comment: can you send for me all file jasper? (phuongph@telsoft.com.vn)

Comment: I have sent for you :)